# Is there a better solution to this if statement problem?

Tags: bash

Bash function to execute a git pull in all subfolder where a .git directory is found.

I'm having issues with the last elif.

This part:

```
...
elif [ $answer == '' || $answer -ne 'y' || $answer -ne 'n' ] ; then
    echo '---Please answer with y/n---'
...
```

Whole code of the function:

```
dogitpull () {
  for i in */.git; do ( echo $i; cd $i/..; ); done
  echo -n 'Are you sure? (y/n) '
  read answer
  echo $answer
  if [ $answer == 'n' ] ; then
    echo '---CANCELED---'
  elif [ $answer == 'y' ] ; then
    echo '---------------------------'
    for d in */.git; do ( echo $d; cd $d/..; git pull; echo '---------------------------'; ); done
  elif [ $answer == '' || $answer -ne 'y' || $answer -ne 'n' ] ; then
    echo '---Please answer with y/n---'
fi
}
```

If the answer is empty (pressed enter), is not 'y' or is not 'n' there should be the text "Please answer with y or n" and should start again from the "read answer".

Does anybody have a solution to this?

Output: when pressing enter

```
-bash: [: ==: unary operator expected
-bash: [: ==: unary operator expected
-bash: [: missing `]'
-bash: -ne: command not found
-bash: -ne: command not found
```

Output: when entering something else than y or n

```
-bash: [: missing `]'
-bash: a: command not found
-bash: a: command not found
```

Comment: for such cases you can use `case` : https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html or search stackoverflow for `bash case`

Comment: @George Vasiliou Thanks, that helped with the errors
Can I somehow start from the top again?

Comment: Nevermind solved it

Comment: I would just use `find`, if you already have a solution though FabuM you should post it

Comment: `||` is not a valid operator for the `[` command. See shellcheck.net.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you didn't quote the variable. When `$answer` is empty then `[ $answer == '' ]` expands to `[ == '' ]` which gives an error since there is nothing on the left hand side of the `==`.

#### Fix

Quote your your variable and then proceed to fix the following errors (courtesy of Kamil Cuk):

- `-ne` is for numbers, it will error with `"Integer expression expected"`. Use `!=` instead.
- `||` is not valid for `[`. Use `-o` or put the `||` outside the braces: `[ ... ] || [ ... ] || [ .. ]`

```
elif [ "$answer" = '' ] || [ "$answer" != 'y' ] || [ "$answer" != 'n' ]
```

#### Improvements

- Use a single `=` instead of `==`. `[ a = b]` is the official and portable way to check equality of `a` and `b`.
- Instead of `elif [ "$answer" == '' || "$answer" -ne 'y' || "$answer" -ne 'n'` you may want to write just `else` which has the samme effect due to the preceding `if`-cases.

```
if [ "$answer" = 'n' ] ; then
    # ...
elif [ "$answer" = 'y' ] ; then
    # ...
else
    # ...
fi
```

Comment: `"$answer" -ne 'y'` - `-ne` is for numbers, it will error with "Integer expression expected". You should use `!=`. Also `||` is not valid for `[`. You can `[ ... ] || [ ... ] || [ .. ]`.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. I Just fixed the first error I spotted and copied the remaining flawed code. Never tried it since a simple `else` will do the same job. ---- I added your hints to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

use case. example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n 'Are you sure? (y/n) '
read answer
echo $answer
case "$answer" in
        n|N) echo '---CANCELED---';;
        y|Y) echo '-- yes ---';;
        *) echo '---Please answer with y/n---';;
esac
```

Comment: `echo` and `read` can be replaced by a single command: `read -p "Are you sure?" answer`

Answer (score 0):

If answer is not a `y` *and* it is not an `n`, then you need to take action.

```
elif [ "$answer" != 'y' ] && [ "$answer" != 'n' ]; then
   echo  '---Please answer with y/n---'
```

Or you can do Moore's law and:

If not both: answer is 'Y' or answer is 'n', then you need to take action.

```
elif ! { [ "$answer" = 'y' ] || [ "$answer" = 'n' ]; }; then
   echo  '---Please answer with y/n---'
```

or with a `(` subshell:

```
elif ! ( [ "$answer" = 'y' ] || [ "$answer" = 'n' ] ); then
   echo  '---Please answer with y/n---'
```